# Confirm aot / prod build works without emitting

Tags: angular

I have some code in Angular that succeeds type checking, linting, and dev builds, but not production (aot) builds (`ng build --prod`).

```
@Component({
  template: `{{ service.value }}`
})
ComponentClass {
  constructor(private service: Service) {}
}
```

I realize this specific issue is because of https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11978, but there are other issues that can come up. I can fix this simply by changing `private` to `public`, for example, but that's not my question.

Is there any way to check that `ng build --prod` will succeed without actually completing the build? I'm not sure when Angular actually checks the things reporting the errors such as the one above, so I'm not sure what exact command, if any, can do this check. I would like to use it as a commit hook; ideally it could be done in tandem with type checking / linting as well to reduce commit hook time. Is there any way to perform this check?

Comment: Considering the github issue says _in JiT mode, we're not using Typescript - we're generating ES5 code_, I _think_ the error is thrown by the typescript compiler, so you might want to try manually compiling using the `tsc` installed

Comment: Why not do `ng build --prod` in a commit hook? It can catch this issue and other issues which might not be documented yet? For real time info during development though, you might want to look into IDE plugins.

Comment: @AyushGupta `ng build --prod` is fine, it's just that it creates the build directory; I don't necessarily want to do that, although it wouldn't be the worst thing in the world. Also I'm wondering if there is some faster / better way to check this.